# Erro na solução de um problema da OBI

Tags: c++

Estou tentando resolver o problema [Wifi](https://olimpiada.ic.unicamp.br/pratique/p2/2018/f2/wifi/) da OBI 2018 e tive a ideia de criar um código que vai ler e armazenar as coordenadas das salas e, depois, checar se ela está "acoplando"(por fora de) outra sala. Depois disso, o código deve somar 1 para cada sala que não é interna a outra, assim obterei o valor necessário de wifi's. Porém, toda vez que o código é executado, ele retorna o número total de salas, causando erro. Segue abaixo o código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int N, res = 0;
    typedef struct{
        long int x1, y1, x2, y2;
        int e;
    }sala;
    cin >> N;
    sala v[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        cin >> v[i].x1 >> v[i].y1 >> v[i].x2 >> v[i].y2;
        v[i].e = 1;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
            if(v[i].x1 < v[j].x1 && v[i].y1 < v[j].y1 && v[i].x2 > v[j].x2 && v[i].y2 > v[j].y2){
                v[i].e = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        res += v[i].e;
    }
    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comparações estão erradas. Substitua:

```
  if(v[i].x1 < v[j].x1 && v[i].y1 < v[j].y1 && v[i].x2 > v[j].x2 && v[i].y2 > v[j].y2){
```

por:

```
 if(v[i].x1 < v[j].x1 && v[i].y1 > v[j].y1 && v[i].x2 > v[j].x2 && v[i].y2 < v[j].y2){
```

e o seu algorítimo vai funcionar.

Bem, eu testei esse algoritmo com a correção no site da OBI e o resultado foi 20/100. Então, eu tentei dar uma otimizada,mas o máximo que eu consegui foi uma versão avaliada com 80/100. Se você tiver interesse, segue a versão otimizada:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Sala {
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2;
    int y2; 
};

int main() {

    int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    std::vector<Sala> salas;
    salas.reserve(N);

    int x1, y1, x2, y2;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        std::cin >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;
        salas.push_back({ x1, y1, x2, y2 });
    }
    //ordena as salas tomando como parâmetro a posição do lado esquerdo
    //o tempo perdido com a ordenação é mais do que compensado nos loops abaixo
    std::sort(salas.begin(), salas.end(), [](Sala i, Sala j) {return i.x1 < j.x1; });

    int output = N;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        /*o segundo loop é iniciado com j = i, pois como houve a ordenação
        sala[i] nunca estará dentro de sala[j].
        O loop se encerra quando sala[j].x1 for maior ou igual a sala[i].x2, pois as 
        salas que se iniciam depois do lado direito da sala[i] não podem estar dentro de sala[i]
        */
        for (int j = i; j < N && !(salas[j].x1 >= salas[i].x2); j++) {
            if (i == j) { continue; }           
            if (salas[j].x2 < salas[i].x2 && salas[j].y1 < salas[i].y1 && salas[j].y2 > salas[i].y2) {
                output--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << output;

    return 0;
}
```